Assessing for statistical significance of change in trend rate of events with survival analysis in R
I have data examining the date of an event following a particular procedure among different sampled individuals. I expect that within X days of the procedure, the rates of my event will increase and then return to baseline after X days have passed. My goal in this test is to see if there is an overall change in trend across my dataset.
I was planning to do a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with a uniform rate. I tried to do this in R and received an error saying, "Ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test." My data has ties as multiple people can have the event occur on the same post-procedure day.
Here is an example of my data and my method.
day_of_event <- c(1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 12, 16, 16, 17, 19, 21)

ks.test(day_of_event, "punif", min = 0, max = 21)
Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  days
D = 0.31429, p-value = 0.1033
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test.default(days, "punif", min = 0, max = 21) :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Is there an alternative method to this analysis?
(How to test change in rate of event occurrences?) This previous thread suggests calculating inter-arrival times although I'm not sure this method would work for two reasons. The inter-arrival times are meaningless values in this context and don't address the ties.
